# HTTP Post assistance through Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, http

Thank you for any assistance you can provide! I seem to have hit a blocking point.
I am attempting to send a data string from within an Excel spreadsheet to a given HTTP location. Eventually I will wish to send actual data fields in the string, but for now I am just hard-coding to get a POC working.

After researching other posts on this same subject, I have come up with the code example below, however when attempting to make the connection, I receive a "400 Bad Request" web error.

Can anyone spot what I am doing wrong in my syntax?

```
Sub HTTPpost()

Dim result As String
Dim myURL As String
Dim postData As String
Dim winHttpReq As Object

Set winHttpReq = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")

myURL = "Insert URL Location"  
postData = "Insert Data String"

winHttpReq.Open "POST", myURL, False
winHttpReq.SetCredentials "Insert ID", "Insert Pwd", 0
winHttpReq.SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
winHttpReq.Send (postData)

result = winHttpReq.ResponseText
Debug.Print vbCrLf & "Results:" & vbCrLf & result

End Sub
```

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure this out. According to the receiving application, the UserID and Pwd needed to be within the DATA string, not a separate credential.
So the end result that works looks like this:

```
Sub HTTPpost()

Dim result As String
Dim myURL As String
Dim postData As String
Dim winHttpReq As Object

Set winHttpReq = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")

myURL = "Insert URL Location"  
postData = "Insert ID & Insert Pwd & Insert Data String"

winHttpReq.Open "POST", myURL, False
winHttpReq.SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
winHttpReq.Send (postData)

result = winHttpReq.ResponseText
Debug.Print vbCrLf & "Results:" & vbCrLf & result

End Sub
```